# Why does VSCode print the abbreciation marks, commas and the brackets?

Tags: python, output

Im a newcomer to programming and I cant figure out why VS Code prints " , (), and commas. I just want a clean output and have achieved this in the past, but somehow it doesn't work for me at the moment. Not only is it annoying, I would really like to find out the problem behind this... My written code is the following:

```
# Initialisierung
jung = 6
erwachsen = 9
alt = 12
# Verarbeitung
schritt = 0
while schritt < 3:
    schritt = schritt + 1
    hilf = erwachsen*4 + alt*2
    alt = erwachsen // 3
    erwachsen = jung // 2
    jung = hilf
    gesamt = jung + erwachsen + alt
    # Ausgabe
    print("")
    print("")
    print('Anzahl der Schritte: ', schritt)
    print("")
    print("Jung:" , jung)
    print('Erwachsen:' , erwachsen)
    print('Alt: ' , alt)
    print("Gesamt:" , gesamt)
    print("")
```

And my output in Terminal is:

```
('Anzahl der Schritte: ', 1)
('Jung:', 60)
('Erwachsen:', 3)
('Alt: ', 3)
('Gesamt:', 66)
('Anzahl der Schritte: ', 2)
('Jung:', 18)
('Erwachsen:', 30)
('Alt: ', 1)
('Gesamt:', 49)
```

Just want to remove the unnecessary marks for a better output (for example I thought my code would be displayed in the following way:
`Anzahl der Schritte: 2`

instead of:

```
('Anzahl der Schritte: ', 2)
```

Would really appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: Presumably you're running it with Python 2, not 3, where print is a statement not a function so you're giving it tuples.

Comment: It's the other way around, in python 2 print is a statement. EDIT: see that you have pointed out that from the output it looks like print is being treated as a statement, hence it's printing a tuple (and running python2). Need to learn to read!

Answer (score -1):

Try fstrings

```
print(f"Anzahl der Schritte: {schritt}")
```

Or, if that doesn't work as you're on python2 then either update to python3 (recommended) or use % formatting:

```
print "Anzahl der Schritte: %d" % (schritt)
```

Or string concatenation

```
print("Anzahl der Schritte: " + str(schritt))
```

Comment: This doesn't explain or actually solve the problem, just defers it (or not, even: f-strings definitely don't work in 2) until the OP hits the next incompatibility between the version they think they're running and the one they actually are.

Comment: Updated to account for python2. You could comment and say that OP should check their python version with `python -v` or `import sys;sys.version_info`